# do-release-upgrade fails with "could not calculate the upgrade"

Tags: apt, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I'm having trouble upgrading my Macbook Pro retina from 13.04 to 13.10. Any help is appreciated.

[/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6946153/)

[/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6946182/)

Answer (score 0):

**Upgrade release interrupted or broken :**

When you do an release upgrade, many problems can occur : the computer brutally stops, internet access stops, ... It is then possible to have an incomplete upgrade or some problem with dependencies.

- In case you have dependencies errors, try theses commands :

  ```
  sudo dpkg --configure -a
  ```

  and then :

  ```
  sudo apt-get install -f
  ```
- If your upgrade was interrupted or a major issue occured, you can try this command :

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a
  ```

  This will reinstall and reconfigure every package needed for the release-upgrade. Please note that this can be very long, up to 1 hour.

*Source : [ubuntu-fr.org](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/migration#mise_a_niveau_interrompue_ou_defectueuse)*